# cURL запрос и задача cron

Tags: php, curl, cron, instagram

друзья, есть такой скрипт, который реализует подписку на пользователя инстаграм

```
<?php
    $user_id = '44****6';
    $token = '***011c2459bf';
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/relationship?';
    $token_params = array("access_token" => $token ,
                               "action" => "follow");
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token_params);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    ?>
```

если запускать файл через браузер, то все работает, если же через cron, то результата нет.

пробовал логировать ответ

```
$results = json_decode($result, true);
if($results)
    fwrite($log, "\n".date('c').' JSON декодировали');
else {
    fwrite($log, "\n".date('c').' JSON не получилось декодировать');
    if($results===NULL)
    fwrite($log,"\n\tСлишком глубокая рекурсия или в данных чушь");
  exit(5);
}

foreach ($results as $result) {
    foreach ($result as $product) {
       fwrite($log,"\n\t".date('c').' ['.$key.'] => '.$product);
    }
}
```

в ответ пишет

```
2017-05-08T21:00:51+03:00 JSON декодировали
2017-05-08T21:00:51+03:00 [] => follows
2017-05-08T21:00:51+03:00 [] => none
2017-05-08T21:00:51+03:00 [] => 
2017-05-08T21:00:51+03:00 [] => 200
```

Это как раз то, что должен возвращать инстаграмм при успешном запросе, но подписка не была выполнена. В чем у меня проблема?

upd:  выяснил, что file_get_contents тоже не выполняется под кроном. А из под браузера все ок. Такое ощущение, что запросы на сторонние сервера вообще не выполняются под кроном

```
$request_params = array('access_token' => '140******9bf');
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?'.$get_params));
$res =  $result->data->counts->media;
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, $kek ."\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```